# clearInterval() not working

Tags: javascript, timer

Session length is the start time of the timer, default is 25. isEven is used to start/stop the timer, if isEven is false, the timer should start, if it is odd it should hit clearInterval, which for some reason is not stopping execution of tick() function (which counts down the timer).

```
var count = 0;

function countdown(sessionLength) {
  var minutes = sessionLength - 1;
  var seconds = 60;
  var isEven = false;
  count++;

  if (count % 2 == 0) {
    isEven = true;
  } else {
    isEven = false;
  }

  var myVar = setInterval(tick, 1000);

  if (isEven == false) {
    function tick() {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
      } else {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;
      }

      if (minutes > 0) {
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
          minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds.toString();
      } else {
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
          "0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds.toString();
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.log("reached");
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
};
```

Comment: You're passing tick to the setInterval when it doesn't actually exist (because it's in an if block)

Answer (score 0):

Move the `tick()` function declaration outside of the `if` block

Answer (score 0):

setInterval variable is a local one. So its value is overwritten every time you call `countdown`

. The solution would be to initialize `myVar` outside the function `countdown` or to make it a global variable like this :
        `window.myVar =setInterval (tick,1000);`

You have also to put this instruction in the first `if` block, so that it is not overwritten everytime

```
var count = 0;  
function  countdown(sessionLength)  { 
var minutes = sessionLength - 1; 
var seconds = 60; 
var isEven = false; 
count++; 
if (count % 2 == 0) { 
    isEven = true; 
} else { 
    isEven = false;
} 
if (isEven == false) { 
    window.myVar = setInterval(tick, 1000);
   function tick() { 
      if (seconds > 0) {  
          seconds--;  
      } else {  
          minutes--; seconds = 59;  
      } 
      if (minutes > 0)  {  
         document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds.toString();  
     } else { 
          document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds.toString(); 
     } 
   } 
} else { 
     console.log("reached");  
     if (window.myVar){  
          clearInterval(window.myVar); 
          window.myVar = null;
      }
} 
};
```

Comment: Thank your for your response.

At the last if statement what does if(window.myVar) evaluate to? If myVar is not of type boolean, how does it execute the statement?

Comment: In javascript, `if (variable)` return false if the `variable` is a `false` boolean value, null, undefined or empty string. Otherways, it returns `true`. I added this in your case because myVar is not necessary defined at that moment or it could be null